# Promise function with FileReader resolves prematurely

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I'm opening a file to read contents like so:

```
convertBlobToBase64(blob){
    var convertPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function() {
          var dataUrl = this.result;
          var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
          resolve(base64);
      };

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });

    return convertPromise;
  }
```

I then call this function and pass the result data when it resolves:

```
myFunction(audioFile){
    var to64 = this.convertBlobToBase64(audioFile);
    to64.then(function(base64Val){
        var nextPromise = postCall();
        nextPromise.then(//stuff);
        return nextPromise;
    });

    return to64;
}
```

However, when I call myFunction, it immediately returns a resolved promise that includes the converted data from `convertBlobToBase64`, and not an unresolved promise that should be waiting on `nextPromise` as expected.

Instead, myFunction's .then is called immediately and fails as it doesn't have the correct data. Am I misunderstanding the Promise function?

Comment: Why do you need base64?

Comment: @Endless To send the audio content to the server.

Comment: Can't you just send it as is? with [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)? base64 is ~3x larger in size

Comment: @Endless can you elaborate on that? When I didn't encode to base64 the audio wasn't loading correctly, would show as corrupted. I am uploading it to dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
myFunction(audioFile){
    var to64 = this.convertBlobToBase64(audioFile);
    return to64.then(function(base64Val){
        var nextPromise = postCall();
        return nextPromise.then(//stuff);
    });
}
```

Comment: that worked, thanks. Can you provide an explanation as to why `return to64` is a preresolved promise?

Comment: If it works, then here's explanation. A promise is a thing that wraps a value. So when you call `then` on a promise it, in turn, returns a new promise. So the line `nextPromise.then(//stuff);` simply ignores the returned promise. I hope that's clear.

Comment: Right, but why wouldn't the line `return to64` be a deferred promise? Why is it already resolved?

Comment: Could be that resolving was that fast haha. I mean `to64` didn't have to wait for things that go in and after `then`.

Answer (score 1):

Btw you dont need to wrap another promise to a function. You can use your postCall as resolve func and chain it like this:

```
myFunction(audioFile){
  return convertBlobToBase64(audioFile)
    .then(base64Val => postCall())
    .then(//stuff)
}
```